The Ultimate Battle of two players
The Ultimate Battle is a turn-based two-player game.
Player $i$ (1 or 2) has three stats: initial hit point $P_i$, attack $A_i$, and heal $H_i$. The values can differ between players. All values are positive integers.
When the game begins, player 1 has hit point $P_1$ and player 2 has $P_2$. Player 1 plays first. On player $i$'s turn, they can choose either to attack or heal. If they attack, the opponent's hit point is reduced by $A_i$. If they heal, their own hit point increases by $H_i$. At any point, a player wins if the opponent's hit point is 0 or lower. There is no upper limit for players' hit points; specifically, they can go above the initial hit points.
Both players play optimally: if they can win, they always make a move that leads to a win; otherwise, they make a move that leads to an infinite game if possible. Identify the condition for each player to win.

Solution
Define the recovery ratios $R_i$ for player $i$
$$R_1 = \frac{H_1}{A_2} \text{ and }R_2 = \frac{H_2}{A_1}$$ and the "turns-to-die" $T_i$ for player $i$
$$T_1=\Big\lceil\frac{P_1}{A_2}\Big\rceil \text{ and }  T_2 = \Big\lceil\frac{P_2}{A_1}\Big\rceil.$$
A trivial case when player $1$ wins is $A_1 > P_2.$ We will ignore this case in further discussions.
Also define the dominating attack conditions $D_1$ a (true/false value) $$D_1=\big( T_1\ge T_2\big),$$ and $D_2 = \text{ not }D_1$.
Then the result can be summarised by the following table (subscript indicates the part of the proof)
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  R_1 \backslash R_2 & >1 & =1 & <1 \\
  \hline\\
  >1 & \infty_{a} & \infty_{a} & 1_{b} \\
  \hline\\
  =1 & \infty_{a} & \infty_{a} & 
\begin{array}{}
D_1\Rightarrow 1_c\\ 
D_2\Rightarrow \infty_b
\end{array} \\
  \hline\\
  <1 & 2_{b} & 
\begin{array}{}
D_1\Rightarrow \infty_c\\ 
D_2\Rightarrow 2_c\end{array} & 
\begin{array}{}
D_1\Rightarrow 1_a\\ 
D_2\Rightarrow 2_a\end{array}
\end{array}
$$
Reasoning
The trivial case of $A_1 > P_2$ leads to player $1$'s win on the first move. As above, we will ignore this case in the following.
The part $\infty_a$ is clear, because if both players' recovery ratios are $\ge 1$, then no persistent decrease in the hit-points of either player can be made.
The part $1_a$: If $R_1 < 1 \text{ and } R_2 < 1$, then no player should choose to heal. Since it takes $T_i$ hits to kill player $i$, we have that player $1$ wins if and only if $T_1\ge T_2$.
Symmetry in $1_a$ also proves $2_a$.
The part $1_b$ (see the Appendix as to why this part is so complex): Let $R_1 > 1 \text{ and } R_2 < 1$. Note that an infinite game is not possible, so if player $1$ does not win, then player $2$ must win. Notice that player $2$ is strictly worse if it does the opposite action as player $1$. If $D_1$ is not satisfied at the beginning of the game, player $1$ will heal (and force player $2$ to heal). The condition to have $D_1$ (on player $1$'s turn) eventually is
$$\Big\lceil \frac{P_1 + nH_1}{A_2}\Big\rceil\ge \Big\lceil\frac{P_2+nH_2}{A_1}\Big\rceil$$
for some $n$. Since $R_1=\frac{H_1}{A_2}>1$ and $R_2=\frac{H_2}{A_1}<1$, the left hand side will increase faster than the right hand side. When this happens, player $1$ will start always attacking (and force player $2$ to attack) and win according to $1_a$.
Symmetry in $1_b$ also proves $2_b$.
Edge cases
It remains to check the cases when one of $R_i$ is $1$ and the other is $<1$. Essentially, the solution is the same as that of $R_1 < 1 \text{ and } R_2 < 1$, except the player with $R_i = 1$ can force an infinite game by healing (thank you @Tom Sirgedas for this concise summary).
Part $1_c$: If $R_1=1$ and $R_2<1$ and $D_1$, then player $1$ will win the game by constantly attacking, according to arguments in $1_a$ and $1_b$.
Part $\infty_b$: If $R_1=1$ and $R_2<1$ and $D_2$, then player $1$ cannot win immediately by attacking, according to arguments in $1_a$. Notice that player $1$ can guarantee that it will not lose. But if player $1$ attempts to heal, then player $2$ will attack, bringing everything to where we started. So the game is infinite.
Part $2_c$: If $R_1<1$ and $R_2=1$ and $D_2$, then player $1$ will not heal to start, because then player $2$ will attack, and player $1$ is strictly worse. So player $1$ must attack and lose to an all-attack battle due to $D_2$.
Part $\infty_c$: If $R_1 < 1$ and $R_2 = 1$ and $D_1$, then player $2$ can guarantee to not lose. As in part $(2.3)$, player $1$ will not heal to start. But when player $1$ attacks, then player $2$ will heal, which brings everything back to the beginning.
Appendix
To see why part $1_b$ is so complex, consider the following example:
$$\begin{array}{c|rr}
  & 1 & 2\\
\hline
H & 10 & 50 \\
A & 51 & 9 \\
P & 10 & 1000 \\
\end{array}
$$
where $R_1=10/9>1$ and $R_2=50/51<1$ but $H_1<H_2$. Obviously player $1$ cannot lose because $R_1>1$, though it is not intuitive that player $1$ can win by healing, as the opponent can heal five times more per turn and has a huge lead in HP. However, the condition in the proof is still satisfied as
$$\Big\lceil \frac{10 + 10n}{9}\Big\rceil\ge \Big\lceil\frac{1000+50n}{51}\Big\rceil$$
is satisfied if $n\ge 142$ (I ignored the ceiling functions to make calculations easier).

If $A_1>P_2$, player 1 wins on their first turn.
Otherwise,
Let's categorize both players.
$$
 \text{A player is} 
 \begin{cases}
 \text{an }\textbf{over-healer} & \text{if their heal is greater than the opponent's attack} \\
 \text{an }\textbf{exact-healer} & \text{if their heal is equal to the opponent's attack} \\
 \text{a }\textbf{bad-healer} & \text{if their heal is less than the opponent's attack} \\
 \end{cases}
$$
Then, the outcome of the battle is
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{} & \text{Player 1 is over-healer} & \text{Player 1 is exact-healer} & \text{Player 1 is bad-healer} \\ 
\hline
   \text{Player 2 is over-healer} & \text{Draw} & \text{Draw} & \text{Player 2 wins} \\
\hline
   \text{Player 2 is exact-healer} & \text{Draw} & \text{Draw} & \text{Special Scenario} \\
\hline
   \text{Player 2 is bad-healer} & \text{Player 1 wins} & \text{Special Scenario}  & \text{Fight Scenario} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$
Notes:

Only bad-healers can be forced to lose.
Healing is never helpful for a bad-healer (the opponent can reply with an attack), so we can assume that a bad-healer always attacks.

Scenario details:
If neither player is a bad-healer: (Draw)
Neither player can force a win. The battle will be a Draw.
bad-healer vs bad-healer: (Fight Scenario)
Player 1 requires $W1=\lceil\frac{P_2}{A_1}\rceil$ attacks to win.
Player 2 requires $W2=\lceil\frac{P_1}{A_2}\rceil$ attacks to win.
If $W1 \leq W2$, player 1 wins, otherwise player 2 wins.
Over-healer vs bad-healer: (over-healer wins)
The bad-healer never heals, and the over-healer has effectively unlimited hit points by healing. The over-healer can safely attack whenever their hit points exceed the opponent's attack. The over-healer wins.
Exact-healer vs bad-healer: (Special Scenario)
The result is the same as the bad-healer vs bad-healer scenario, except that this time exact-healer has the option to force a draw by always healing.

What about the case where (A,H,P) of (5,0,5) and (4,5,6).  Player 1 is not invincible because he cannot outheal Player 2.  Player 2 is invincible because Player 1 cannot kill him (but not sure if this is necessarily "Outheal").  However, Player 2 does not have the tempo to defeat Player 1.

Good catch. That's a special case I'm not currently handling.

I fixed it, but now I think it's just a less formal version of Benjamin Wang's answer.

There's value in the simplicity if it's accurate.  I haven't even read Benjamin's whole answer yet.

@TomSirgedas thank you for your answer which inspired me to make mine neater and more symmetrical! I added an Appendix to my answer which explains why the over-healer vs bad-healer scenario may not be as intuitive as one might think.
